# Color a set of fragments in fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, webgl, fragment-shader

My goal is to color a set of fragments determined by the interpolation between two points. Below the code I've written, It didn't work.!.

I also added some comments, Probably there are some mistakes I made or something that I misunderstood.

Thank you for your help.

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main(){
    vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
    vec4 color = vec4(0.97, 0.1, 0.53, 1.0);
    
    // center (hopefully)
    vec2 P1 = vec2(0.0,0.0);
    // top right
    vec2 P2 = vec2(1.0,1.0);
    
    // generate 100 points between P1...P2
    for(float i = 0.0; i < 1.0; i+=0.01) {
        float lerpX = mix(P1.x, P2.x, i);
        float lerpY = mix(P1.y, P2.y, i);
        vec2 interpolatedPoint = vec2(lerpX, lerpY);

        // check if current fragment is one of the
        // interpolated points and color it
        if (position.x == interpolatedPoint.x) {
            gl_FragColor = color;
        } else {
            discard;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you try to `discard` fragments? `position.x == interpolatedPoint.x` is a floating point comparison. Your code will discard all fragments. Try `if (abs(position.x - interpolatedPoint.x) < 0.1)`

Comment: Thank you, It didn't work the abs(...) check, and by floating point comparison you mean a memory location comparison (reference comparison) or value comparison, as far as I know the position.x in a webgl canvas spans from -1 to 1, so there must be some points that intersect with the interpolated points. perhaps I'm confused about how comparison works in glsl.

Comment: *"there must be some points that intersect with the interpolated points."* No. `position.x == interpolatedPoint.x` means that the values of both side have to exactly the same with floating point accuracy. The fragment shader is just executed once for each fragment.

Comment: It worked, **thank you for your help**, I edited the question with a working solution. Can you suggest any materials/resources to better understand how shader works. Thank you again.

Comment: I have one more question if you may, how many times a fragment shader will be called in for example a 100x100 unit canvas. does it depend on precision qualifier, like if it's lowp for example it will be called 100*100 times ?

Comment: Do not add a solution to the question! You have to put the solution into an answer. You can even answer your own question.

Comment: If the size of the viewport is 100x100, then the fragment shader is called 10000 times (if multisampling is off).

Comment: can I assume that **position.x** at the first fragment call is **0.0** and for the last call is **100.0** ?

Comment: No. In general it is the "center" of the fragment, 0.5 respectively 99.5

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do but just FYI, this is about the slowest possible way you could draw 100 points using WebGL and it will get slower and slower the larger the size of your canvas. You'd be far better off using more traditional techniques using vertices then trying to do it all in the fragment shader.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to find an efficient way to implement rendering/editing of multiple Bezier Curves give 4 points each. Ironically I thought if I pass less data to the vertex shader and let the fragment shader do the hard work, that'd be faster. I wasn't sure whether calling gl.draw multiple times for each curve is faster or send all curves data to the vertex shader and draw them at once is better. Perhaps I still don't fully understand the graphics pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

`position.x == interpolatedPoint.x` is a floating point comparison and is almost never evaluated as true. Your code discards all fragments. Implement a floating point comparison. Calculate the absolute value of the difference between the two values and compare it with an epsilon:

```c
if (distance(position, interpolatedPoint) <= 0.01) {
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**WORKING SOLUTION**

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main(){
    vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
    vec4 color = vec4(0.97, 0.1, 0.53, 1.0);
    
    // center (hopefully)
    vec2 P1 = vec2(0.0,0.0);
    // top right
    vec2 P2 = vec2(1.0,1.0);
    
    // generate 100 points between P1...P2
    for(float i = 0.0; i < 1.0; i+=0.01) {
        float lerpX = mix(P1.x, P2.x, i);
        float lerpY = mix(P1.y, P2.y, i);
        vec2 interpolatedPoint = vec2(lerpX, lerpY);

        // check if current fragment is one of the
        // interpolated points and color it
        if (distance(position, interpolatedPoint) <= 0.01) {
            gl_FragColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```